# Export REACT_EDITOR for VSCode

Tags: react-native, redux, visual-studio-code, react-redux, vscode-debugger

How do you complete the following `PRO TIP` from the Android emulator node using the Windows cmd line for VSCode?

"When you see Red Box with stack trace, you can click any
  stack frame to jump to the source file. The packager will launch your
  editor of choice. It will first look at REACT_EDITOR environment
  variable, then at EDITOR. To set it up, you can add something like
  export REACT_EDITOR=atom to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` depending on
  which shell you use."

Should I use `export REACT_EDITOR=code`?

In what directory?

I can't find `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` folders anywhere.

Comment: These are hidden files in your home directory. If they don't exist you'd have to create them. The export is just adding an environment variable. If you are in Windows you can set environment variables in Control Panel (System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables).

Answer (score 27):

Here's how to do it in OS X:

1) Add `REACT_EDITOR=code` to your `.env.local` file

2) Install command `code` by following [Launching from the command line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac) here

3) Restart debugger

4) Profit!

Comment: thank you finally worked!
I exported from my .zsh with
 
export REACT_EDITOR=code
 
IMPORTANT I had to remove old aliaser or other custom functions is my .zsh / .zprofile / or anyhwere!

Answer (score 6):

Forgive if this answer doesn't work for android. **If you're doing react for web and land here:**

You can add

`REACT_EDITOR=code`

to an `.env.local` file in your project root if you use `create-react-app`

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

More info on the `.env` file pattern: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#what-other-env-files-can-be-used

Comment: this was simple enough
from VScode open "command plate" and follow below explanation. 
https://blog.jstassen.com/2020/10/setup-vscode-with-react_editor-or-any-editor/